# Bitnami MEAN Stack on Google Cloud Platform - how to run both express AND rockmongo?

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, mean-stack, bitnami

I followed the instructions on how to modify the bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file to have apache serve up the custom node app.  However, when I do that, rockmongo is no longer accessible.  Is it possible to run both?  Right now my work around is to keep modifying this file and restarting apache whenever i want to get into rockmongo by commenting out my custom node module.

Example of the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file:

```
# Bitnami applications installed in a prefix URL
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/rockmongo/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/customapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

Comment: Hi, It could depend on the Apache configuration used for the app. It may be conflictive with the rockmongo one. Could you provide with the custom app configuration?

Comment: @DavidGomez Just the normal conf file per the instructions for a custom app. ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3001/.  I even tried a different port to make sure it wasn't on the same one as rockmongo.

Comment: As suggestion, you could try with a NodeJs app from the Bitnami library (from instance Parse), and try to use the same Apache logic for your custom app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from the Bitnami folks and here's the solution that fixed my issue on Google Cloud:

If you want to serve RockMongo at example.com/rockmongo your configuration file /opt/bitnami/apps/rockmongo/conf/httpd-prefix.conf should look like:

```
Alias /rockmongo/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/rockmongo/htdocs/"
Alias /rockmongo "/opt/bitnami/apps/rockmongo/htdocs"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/rockmongo/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

In order to have your custom app at blingnightout.com/ your configuration file "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf" should look like:

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

and your configuration file /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf:

```
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ProxyPass /bitnami !
ProxyPass /rockmongo !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Finally, the file /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf should look like:

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/rockmongo/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

Remember to restart Apache to apply the new configuration:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```